Prometheus uses snmp_exporter to collect data
Prometheus is using snmp_exporter to monitor the storage system, the information collected from oid is written to label_value, the value queried using PromQL is always 1, is there any way to output the value of label_value as a value?
I have tried many ways to get the value accurately.
The snmp.yml file configuration looks roughly like this:

name: CPUUsage
oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25506.2.6.1.1.1.1.6
type: gauge
help: The CPU usage for this entity - 1.3.6.1.4.1.25506.2.6.1.1.1.1.6

The statement I use with PromQL is：
CPUUsage
The result:
CPUUsage{CPUUsage="15",instance="X.X.X.X",job="snmp"}   1
I would like to have the figure 15 as a result instead of 1. What do I have to do?
